# Access scala class fields in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have defined the class `A` in Scala:

```scala
class A(var number: Int)
```

But when I try to access its member field `number` in java, I get an error:

```java
A a = new A();
a.number = 4;
```

Results in: `java: number has private access in A`.
If I try to access the `number` from scala, there is no problem.

What can I do to get around this issue?

Comment: Does Scala generate the getters and setters by any chance? getNumber() and setNumber(number) ?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge.

Comment: @SørenHN It does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use getter

```
a.number();
```

and setter

```
a.number_$eq(4);
```

instead of the field itself `a.number`.

Or

```
a.getNumber();
a.setNumber(4);
```

if you annotate the field

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class A(@BeanProperty var number: Int)
```

> If I try to access the `number` from scala, there is no problem.

In Scala when you write `a.number` or `a.number = 4` you actually call getter/setter (this is syntax sugar).

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the generated class file when you compile `A.scala`, that can explain getter `number()` and setter method `number_$eq` from Dmytro's answer

```scala
// A.scala
class A(var number: Int)
```

```sh
> scalac A.scala
```

```sh
> javap -p A.class
```

```java
// output of above step

public class A {
  private int number;
  public int number();
  public void number_$eq(int);
  public A(int);
}
```